# Getting a line from a file and splitting into an array

Tags: php, file-get-contents, explode, minecraft

I am creating a a control panel for minecraft servers(It's a game if you did not not know). I need to process the server.properties file in php to get the online-mode field and get it's value. How do I do this? Any idea?

This is an example of server.properties:

```
spawn-protection=16
query.port=25565
generator-settings=
force-gamemode=false
allow-nether=true
gamemode=0
enable-query=true
player-idle-timeout=0
difficulty=1
spawn-monsters=true
op-permission-level=4
announce-player-achievements=true
pvp=true
snooper-enabled=true
level-type=DEFAULT
hardcore=false
venable-command-block=false
max-players=5
rcon.port=25575
server-port=25565
debug=false
texture-pack=
server-ip=
spawn-npcs=true
allow-flight=false
level-name=
view-distance=10
resource-pack=
spawn-animals=true
white-list=false
rcon.password=asd
generate-structures=true
online-mode=true
max-build-height=256
level-seed=
enable-rcon=true
motd=A Minecraft Server
```

And yes, the fields keep juggling around so I can't really predict where the line would be.

Comment: so are u able to get the content of the files in a variable the way its here ?

Comment: Check my answer I updated it. I can't refer to you since you don't have a normal name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parse ini function would be useful

Example:

```
$settings = parse_ini_file('server.properties');
echo $settings['level-type']; //will print DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using, file_get_contents, then you can use explode to break data from new line.

```
  $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/data.txt');

    $arr=explode("\n",$homepage)

    Alternatively, you can use preg_split and the character group \s which matches every white space character:

    preg_split('/\s+/', $homepage);
```

Now for searching for particular keyword:

```
$prop='properties';
$key = array_search($prop, $arr);
```

Bythis you can find the particular position.
now use explode to get the desired result.

```
$res=explode("=",$key);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use explode()

```
$content = file_get_contents('server.properties');
$lines= explode("\r\n" , $content);


echo '<form name="form1" method="post" action="">';

array_pop($lines);

foreach($lines as $line)
{

     $properties = explode('=' , $line);
     echo $properties[0] . ' = <input type="text" value="'. $properties[1] .'" name="properties[]['. $properties[0] .']"/></br>';
}
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></br>';

echo '</form>';
```

The part above echoes the contents of the file.
The part below assembles it. You can put this above the part which is previously mentioned.

```
if(isset($_POST['properties']))
{

    $new_lines = $_POST['properties'];


    $string = '';

    foreach($new_lines as $line)
    {
        foreach($line as $property => $value)
        {
             $string .= $property . '=' . $value . "\r\n";
        }
    }

    file_put_contents('server.properties' , $string);

    unset($_POST['properties']);

}
```

Comment: @user3001689 The solution to your problem. You will have to do the styling in css and html I'm not gonna do that. And make sure the files have the right permissions.

Answer (score 1):

if you are able to get the content of the file in a PHP variable using `file_get_content()` or by some other means and lets say the variable that holds the string is `$input_lines`

You can use the following regex to get the value

```
preg_match_all("/online\-mode=(.*)$/m", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

$output_array will be as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => online-mode=true
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => true
        )

)
```

This is how it works

```
 /online\-mode=(.*)$/m

    online matches the characters online literally (case sensitive)
    \- matches the character - literally
    mode= matches the characters mode= literally (case sensitive)
    1st Capturing group (.*)
        .* matches any character (except newline)
            Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    $ assert position at end of a line
    m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```